# C Pointer to an Array example stops working

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm working on an example and my code is stopped woking when I run it.(Note that I translated the question to English so sorry for grammar mistakes.)
**Here is the question:**

`myShrink()` function's prototype is like this:

```
void myShrink(int *param1, const int param2);
```

`myShrink()` function should find the average of the array `param1` then should increment the element by 1 if its less than average, or should decrement the element by 1 if it's more than average. **`param2` is a number of elements in an array.**

Here is the content of the `main()` function:

```
void myStretch(int *param1, const int param2); 

int main () {  int myArray[] = {2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4}; 

 int index;    
 myStretch(myArray, 6); 

 printf("UPDATED ARRAY: "); 

 for(index = 0; index < 6; index++){
 printf("%d\t", myArray[index]);
 } 

 return 0;
 }
```

**---------The result when we run the program:-----**

**UPDATED ARRAY: 1 5 1 5 1 5**

Now this was the question part what  we need to is basically programming the content of `myShrink()` function and here is my work:

```
void myShrink(int *param1, const int param2)
{
    int array[param2];
    param1=array;//Using pointer to point elements of array
    int average=0;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<param2;i++)
    {
        average+=*(param1 + i);//Adding each element of array
    }
        average=average/param2;//Then dividing result to param2 to find average

    for(j=0;j<param2;j++)
    {
        if(*(param1+j)<average)//if below average
        {
            *(param1+j)+=1;//increment
        }
        else if(*(param1+j)>average)//if above average
        {
             *(param1+j)-=1;//decrement
        }
    }
}
```

But its stops working when I run it. Where I did make mistake and how can I fix it?

Comment: `param1=param2` is going to cause you lots and lots of problems.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers and how can i fix it ?

Comment: `int array[param2];` (an array whose size can't be determined at compile time) is a common compiler extension, but is NOT standard C++.  Use a `std::vector` if you need such a thing (but you're not actually using `array` at all).

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @onurcevik I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish with that line. It doesn't appear to serve any purpose at all.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers i tried to point array elements.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers oh ok. i should make it `param1=array;` but still not working

Comment: @onurcevik I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean when you say "i tried to point array elements".

Comment: @MichaelAlbers here in this link you can see the similiar operation which is`p = balance` in this link.

: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_an_array.htm

Comment: Are you sure you are studying C++ and not some other language like C?

Comment: @n.m. sorry confused it its C not C++ thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @onurcevik In that article they are showing that a raw pointer, such as `int *` can be used to point to, and access, an array. In your case it isn't required at all. The `param1` parameter is already pointing to the array. You are accessing it correctly by `*(param1 + i)`. You can also use the `[]` operator, like `param1[i]`.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers Thanks it solved my problem but can you briefly explain how param1 points the array? Because after removing that line even though it Works i don't see any line that points the array.

Comment: @onurcevik That you will need to research on your own. It'll be better for you in the end if you do the work yourself to understand the relationship between pointers and arrays in C and C++.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers I already did the research i tried to implement that code to my example but it didn't work. I just don't understand in which line param1 points array ? you said i am accessing it correctly by `*(param1+i)` but i don't understand it how it points the array ? Please can you atleast give a tip or anything?

Comment: @onurcevik When passed as parameters, arrays are passed by reference. The reference is a pointer, in this case `param1`. So `myStretch(myArray, 6);` doesn't pass the entire array, just the address of the first element. That address arrives in `myStretch` in `param1`.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers thank you :)

Comment: @onurcevik You're welcome.

Comment: And my request to the community. Please don't downvote so easily. It is really a hard time sometimes for beginners. Instead show the right way.

Comment: @VidorVistrom yes,. it is, which is why, as a beginner, you will have a hard time on a Q&A site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void myStretch(int *param1, const int param2);

int main () {  int myArray[] = {2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4};

int index;
myStretch(myArray, 6);

printf("UPDATED ARRAY: ");

for(index = 0; index < 6; index++){
printf("\n%d\t", myArray[index]);
}

return 0;
}

void myStretch(int *param1, const int param2)
{

int average=0;
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<param2;i++)
{
    average+=*(param1 + i);//Adding each element of array
}
    average=average/param2;//Then dividing result to param2 to find average

for(j=0;j<param2;j++)
{
    if(*(param1+j)<average)//if below average
    {

        (*(param1+j))+=1;//increment
    }
    else if(*(param1+j)>average)//if above average
    {
         printf("%d ",(*(param1+j)));
         (*(param1+j))-=1;//decrement
    }
}
}
```

Now first thing: your result is wrong. It should be 3 3 3 3 3 3. As the average in this case is 3 and therefore 2 will become 3  and 4 will also become 3. Secondly you don't have to assign a new array inside the function. Just do it this way. Third mistake:

```
*(param1+j)>average
```

should be replaced by

```
(*(param1+j))>average
```

and similarly for less than sign.
UPDATE: Also note that many people argue that array[param2] is legal or not. When you declare such an array they are called Variable Length Array(VLA). This is allowed in modern C compilers but older compilers like Turbo C don't allow.

Comment: Thank you. By the way can you explain why `*(param1+j)>average` should be replaced by `(*(param1+j))>average` ? Why brickets matter in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

In below **myShrink** function, after 'param1=array;' statement **param1** start pointing to array which has garbage inside.

```
void myShrink(int *param1, const int param2){
int array[param2];
param1=array;//Using pointer to point elements of array
int average=0;
int i,j;

//debug code to shows param1 points to array which has garage inside
int index =0 ;
for(index = 0; index < 6; index++){
    printf("myDebug: %d\n", param1[index]);
}

for(i=0;i<param2;i++)
{
    average+=*(param1 + i);//Adding each element of array
}
    average=average/param2;//Then dividing result to param2 to find average

for(j=0;j<param2;j++)
{
    if(*(param1+j)<average)//if below average
    {
        *(param1+j)+=1;//increment
    }
    else if(*(param1+j)>average)//if above average
    {
         *(param1+j)-=1;//decrement
    }
}}
```